Removing resistor and replacing it with a voltmeter
This question was in my basic electronics exam today.
What it really asks me to do is to remove R1 which is 1Ω and replace it with a voltmeter that has a reading of 3V and to find the value of V0.
This may seem easy to comprehend but what I really don't get is whether I should take the value of R1 into consideration before placing voltmeter into circuit. Will it change the value of I0 that's going through R2 after I've replaced R1 with a voltmeter as current will not go through there?
Long story short, will removing a 1Ω resistor and replacing it with a voltmeter that has a reading of 3V be any different from a basic circuit with a voltmeter which you can easily solve using Ohm's Law to find the reading of V with the help of V0 (which is not given in this problem)?
Sorry if I've made any mistakes, I really suck at circuits


The fact that there used to be a 1 ohm resistor in the circuit is irrelevant.  You can easily solve the problem with KVL with the given information.

So I guess the voltage drop across R2 after replacing R1 with a voltmeter gives you 3V, according to given information. Agreed that KVL will help you solve the rest.
